# Javascript Object Comparison Test

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, comparison

```
//Testing Function
function testEqual(test, expect, got){
  console.log(`Testing ${test}`);
  if (expect === got){
    console.log(`${test} has passed`);
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log(`${test} has failed, expected ${expect} but got ${got}`);
    return false;
  }
}

//Run the tests
let passed = 0;
let tests = {
  "temperatureCtoF":[75, temperatureCtoF(24)],
  "temperatureInF Part 1":["88F", temperatureInF(88, 'F')],
  "temperatureInF Part 2":["75F", temperatureInF(24, 'C')],
  "makePersonObject": [{"id": 5, "name": 'Leia', "email": 'leia@leia.com'}, makePersonObject(5, "red", "leia@leia.com")],
}
console.log(tests["makePersonObject"]);

console.log(testEqual("makePersonObject", tests["makePersonObject"][0],tests["makePersonObject"][1]));
```

On the above code, I created a testEquals function and a bunch of tests, for the final test, I get the output "Testing makePersonObject
index.js:212 makePersonObject has failed, expected [object Object] but got [object Object]" and I can't seem to figure out how to compare them correctly, I tried using === and .value in my test function but that didn't work.

Comment: Convert them to JSON and compare strings.  Two different objects in memory are not equal, as they reside in different places in memory.

Comment: @Taplar Thank you! My class hasn't gone over JSON yet so it took a little googling but it all worked.